# put_via_redirect need quick example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

i  want  an  example  of  put_via_redirect
my code

```
 describe "PUT /authors/1" do
    it "will update author with id 1" do

    put_via_redirect( author_path(Author.find(1)), {:author => { name: "tim"}} )
    expect(response.body).to include("Tim")

    end
    # ....
 end
```

Active_record  not  found  error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `authors` table is empty. Try populating a sample record before checking the response.

```
Author.create(id: 1, name: 'Tim')
```

Comment: its not empty. i checked it through rails console. how would yo normally test an update using patch_via_redirect. thanks

Comment: your right. i thought i was accessing the DB from my test but im not. So i did this before :all do Author.create(name: "tim"). thanks again